# Click event listener for dynamic/moving anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, click

I'm using a tutorial plugin - http://particlebits.com/code/jquery-tutorial/

which has this code attached to the number of tutorial steps you require.

```
<div for="tutstep4" data-target="#publishbutton" data-arrow="tc" data-location="tr" style="display: block; ">
       <h1>Almost Done!</h1>
       <p>
        Now click "Publish" and you are done.
        </p>
    </div>
```

My question is how do I trigger a click event from the the  tags that are attached to each tutorial step.

```
    <a id="tutorial-done" class="tutorial-button" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display: block; ">Done!</a>
<a id="tutorial-cancel" class="tutorial-cancel" href="javascript:void(0);">X</a>
<a id="tutorial-next" class="tutorial-button" type="button" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display: none; ">Next</a>
<a id="tutorial-prev" class="tutorial-button" type="button" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display: block; ">Prev</a>
```

These tags are moved between steps with the same Id's so if I call

```
$('.tutorial-button').click(function(){
do something
})
```

the button has already been clicked and the function doesn't register.

I dont want to edit the tutorial.js file as it's used across different pages.
Is there something I can do to 'listen' to when '#tutorial-prev' is clicked and then call a function based on the div it' attached to?

i.e. if '#tutorial-prev' is clicked when the tutorial step is 3, do something ?

UPDATE:

After stepping away from it for a while I found an easier solution that simply use a monkey patch on the functions within the script and add my own personal code which consists of opening/closing the required div.

So it was like

```
$.fn.tutorialNext() {
 // start of original next code.
 //end of original code.
 myfunc();
}
```

Not exactly pretty but a quick solution for the one page where I required something customised.

The issue I originally faced was that the anchor tags had already been removed when the Next() function was run so there was no element to perform the function on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have clear what you are trying to achieve, but when you have the click handler:

```
$("'#tutorial-prev").on("click", dosomething);
```

In do something you can replicate the click event everywhere you want with:

```
$(selector).trigger("click");
```

Comment: Also, here is a good explanation of `.on` vs `.click`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 0):

with the js you posted, you bind the click event to every button with the tutorial-button class.

You could further specify a single button by using the element's id, for which you would need to bind one callback to each button.

```
$('#tutorial-prev').click(function(){ //go to previous step });
$('#tutorial-next').click(function(){ //go to next step });
$('#tutorial-cancel').click(function(){ //cancel actions });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

After stepping away from it for a while I found an easier solution that simply use a monkey patch on the functions within the script and add my own personal code which consists of opening/closing the required div.

So it was like

```
$.fn.tutorialNext() {
 // start of original next code.
 //end of original code.
 myfunc();
}
```

Not exactly pretty but a quick solution for the one page where I required something customised.

The issue I originally faced was that the anchor tags had already been removed when the Next() function was run so there was no element to perform the function on.